# Setting an Expiry date for iPhone app

Tags: ios, time

Currently i am developing one gaming iOS application which i will give to some of my customer for demo.

But while distribution of my app i want to set an expiry mechanism in my app, so that it will get expire after "N" number of days.
It means that (e.g. after 30 days) my app won't work.i can able to this by using system date & time, it means whenever my program starts i check today date and expire date.

The problem is if the user changes system time, my comparison won't be correct.

Also if user delete & reinstall the app,it wont work.

Any help or suggestion?

Comment: You know that demos are not allowed in the App Store, right?

Comment: Apple wouldn't let you do this. Try instead to make a "lite" version that has less features. Many apps do this to let people test it out.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist , i know that, but this thing i am not going to put into appstore as of now , this is for internal client demo.

Comment: @user1227928 that is not the norm so you should make it more clear in the question. It is an important price of information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I locally detect iPhone clock advancement by a user between app runs?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7122216)

Answer (score 3):

Look at [Ad Hoc Distribution](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/CreatingandDownloadingaDistributionProvisioningProfile/CreatingandDownloadingaDistributionProvisioningProfile.html)

Ad-hoc development builds last for 3 months, however if you want to add a time limit then you could:

Add a key-value in `NSUserDefaults` which stores the start date of the app (time taken from a webservice such as http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm#timezone) then every time the app enters the foreground check the time against it and if it is over the threshold then to cancel loading the app.

```
NSDate *now        = //load current datetime from restkit
NSDate *startDate  = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"startDate"];
NSDate *futureDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:60 * 60 * 24 * 30 sinceDate:startDate];

if ([futureDate compare:now] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    //stop the application loading by loading a NIB and displaying a message.
}
```

I would recommend using [RestKit](http://restkit.org/) to request data from the web-service.

Comment: just for accuracy: 86400 seconds are not necessarily a day (daylight saving time). while for this task that might not be important, if you want a date EXACTLY in 30 days you date creation with NSDateComponents and NSCalendar instead.

Answer (score 2):

When the app expires, store something in the Keychain to indicate this fact. Then just check that at startup, rather than the date.

Alternatively, you can have it check a web service you control.

Comment: keychain is an better option than nsuserdefaults, as information stored in it wont get deleted with the app. so with user defaults re-installing would ste back the timer. with keychain that wont happen.