# Time difference between set automatically and by user in iOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'll show my question by example.

So, f.e., it's 12:00 (set automatically) now, but user decided to change the current time to 12:10 (it won't be really exact time, but user wants so).

Is there any way to get this 10 minutes in code?

Answer (score 0):

One method is to connect to a time server on your own. Or, if you app is running when it changes, you could keep a timer running and look for discontinuities in time.

Possible duplicate of: [How can I locally detect iPhone clock advancement by a user between app runs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122216/how-can-i-locally-detect-iphone-clock-advancement-by-a-user-between-app-runs)