# Observe changes of system date/time in macOS

Tags: cocoa, macos, datetime, date, time

I'm an iOS developer coming to the Mac. On iOS, we can implement the `applicationSignificantTimeChange:` method in our app delegate or register for the `UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification` notification to react to changes in the system time.

I cannot seem to find an equivalent on the Mac. How can I observe significant changes in the system time (examples: user changes time (zone), switch from/to daylight savings) in macOS (other than starting a timer that fires every second or so)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get notified of a system time change in my Cocoa application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690326/how-can-i-get-notified-of-a-system-time-change-in-my-cocoa-application)

Answer (score 4):

You need to track `NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification`, `NSSystemClockDidChangeNotification`, `NSSystemTimeZoneDidChangeNotification` and `NSWorkspaceDidWakeNotification`  and then re-schedule timers for all significant timestamps such as midnight.

Mac Catalyst does support `UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification`.